# Is it okay to use the word 'Important' negatively?

Tags: word-usage, negation

We can say--

> Five **Important** Tips to Bring Success to Your Business

But then, what about -

> Five **Important** Tips that Bring Failure to Your Business

I was thinking of a title like this -

> Five ***Important*** Factors that Contribute to your Business Failure

OR

> Five **Important** Hazardous Factors that can Make You Sick for More than a Month

Whenever we utter the word 'important', we get a *positive vibe* drawing our attention. Said that, 'important tips' have to be positive. Is it possible to use it in a negative way?

---

I'm **not** asking about using the words - 'unimportant' or 'not-important'.

Comment: I think if "important tips" sound positive, it's not because of "important" but because of "tips". Some Google Books examples: ["the most important evils"](https://www.google.com/search?q="the+most+important+evils"&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: that's interesting @DamkerngT. But do you see that... "the most important..." is *generally* thought to have a positive note

Comment: Even further... can 'tip' be negative then? @DamkerngT. Because 'tip' by definition is just a piece of advice.

Comment: I think I wasn't very careful and as a result my comment may suggest that we should understand English phrases word by word, which in fact is the opposite to my approach.

Comment: You don't use 'tips' alone when the essence will bring failure, 'tips'  are more of digested perspective/advice of the experts based on their knowledge and experience. You need to plug-in the word "avoid" so as not to make the statement sound absurd (the sentence examples aren't wrong, but they're strange, and rather ominous). I'd use, 'Five Important Tips to **Avoid** Bringing Failure to Your Business'. have you tried using the word true, or wise negatively? You can. But you need proper context and skills in using oxymoron (good will seem bad, and vice versa). i.e., true lies, wise fool.

Comment: -2, if it were possible.  Sound Advice on How to Sprain Your Ankle.

Comment: No! 'sound' **is** [a positive word](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sound_3) in itself @TRomano

Comment: You're asking if it is possible to speak nonsense. Yes it is. And it can be grammatical nonsense. "Advice" is the key word, not the adjective. Just as "tips" was the key word in your example, not "important".

Comment: why do you focus on just one word 'tips'? Take on 'factors/things' for that sake. The question is using the word ***important***. Did you read the question? @TRomano

Comment: What do you mean by "okay to use"? Are you asking if it is grammatical? It is grammatical. Is it sane advice? Are they sane tips? No, they are not. Who needs advice on how to sprain their ankle? Who needs tips on how to ruin a business?  That's why I am focusing on "tips".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples give *titles*, not sentences.  The exigencies of title-writing are different from those of sentence-writing.

*Five Important Things that Can Cause a Business to Fail* is grammatical but the title would be better without "important".

"Important" means "having significance" and, by extension, "warranting attention" or "to consider" or "to be considered".

So, in these titles:

*Five Things Warranting Attention that Can Cause a Business to Fail*.

*Five Things to Consider that Can Cause a Business to Fail*.

"warranting attention" and "to consider" are otiose.

P.S. I will also go out on a limb here and say that "important", just like "warranting attention", creates a *virtual* restrictive clause that clashes with the actual restrictive clause in the title.

Comment: This gives a better view +1

Comment: I disagree that the modifier is otiose. There are thousands of factors that contribute to business success and failure. From an article that claimed to be talking about important ones, I would expect an analysis of of not just whether the factor contributed to success or failure, but also how strongly, so as to judge its importance. It might even compare the factors it considers important to other factors that might commonly be considered important. None of those expectations would come to mind without the word important.

Comment: Additionally, this answer never actually addresses whether the word important might not have the right connotation to modify nouns with a negative connotation.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "nouns with a *negative* connotation". Pestilence? Simony?  Larceny? Slime? Excess? Feature-bloat? Taxation?  Hyperbole?